# when will the updated values set in the $set stage be reflected in the pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
 db.col.aggregate( [ $set: { A: 4, B: "$A" } ] )
```

Will the field `B` also be set to `4` within the same stage?

Answer (score 0):

tested.

It will not.

Fields values that are set during the `$set` stage will only reflect in the stages after.